# An ajax call to a url that opens socket.io connection - fails

Tags: ajax, socket.io

I have a node.js server running. It accepts messages via socket.IO.

I need to send messages to the server from some device. This device supports Javascript, but does not support socket.IO commands (it's strange, but that's what I have).

I tried to work around it in the following way:

On my server I put a send.html file that sends a socket.IO message:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:3000/');
  socket.emit('message', 'messages sent');
</script>
```

If I just call this file (localhost/send.html) then everything works fine.

Then I try to call send.html via ajax from the device:

```
<script>
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/send.html", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

and.. nothing happens.

If I try to call any other .html file from the device, then it works. This makes me think that a socket.IO connection cannot be opened by a file that was called by ajax.

However I couldn't find this fact anywhere and anyway, I still need to find a way to send data from the device to socket.IO.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem, or can think of an alternative solution?

Comment: Is the file sending the Ajax request on the same host as the socket file? If not you will have to set a header in the socket file like:  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: This is often a problem when testing locally & the sender & receiver are running on different ports. This then contravenes CORS. As an example, my application server runs on localhost:8500, but my Angular 4 projects run on localhost:4200. I had to set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to '*', to resolve this issue.